# Concatenating a string inside a while loop in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a program in bash which takes as input argument a file name and then takes every line of that file and appends it to a string. At the end, I want to print this string. This is what I wrote (consider that the program name is `concat.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1
STR=""

cat $FILE | while read USER; do
        STR="${STR}${USER}"
done

echo "$STR"
```

And I have the file `stuff.txt`, which has the following:

```
a
b
c
```

And after I run `./concat.sh stuff.txt` I get the empty string. I tried multiple variations of that concatenation, with space, without space (like above), with newline, etc. Still doesn't work. If I try to simply print each line, it works. So if I simply add the line `echo "$USER"` inside the loop I get the correct output, i.e., `a`, `b`, `c` (each on a different line). But that string concatenation still doesn't work. It doesn't work even if I stop using that `$USER` variable in the concatenation. So if I do something like `STR="${STR} abc"` the characters  `abc` are surprisingly not concatenated to `STR`. But if I take this outside of the while loop it actually works (so if I comment the while loop and simply do `STR="${STR} abc"` I will get  `abc` in the string `STR`). I am a newbie in bash and this looks like really weird behaviour to me and have no idea what is going on/how to fix it.

Comment: First don't use upper case variables names if it is just internal to your script since envrionmental and bash internal variables are upper cased. Put an `echo "$USER"` after the shebang of your script and run it, to confirm it. Have a look at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for the issue your having. Also paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for more validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do not use `cat` - ie. do not use pipe. And do not use `USER`.

```
while read var; do
        str="${str}${var}"
done < "$file"
```

Do not use upper case variables in your scripts. `USER` is variable set by bash to the name of current user.

Check scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

[Do not uselessly use cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

In bash you can also use `str+="$var"`.

Quote variable expansions.

Comment: >Just do not use cat - ie. do not use pipe  

Using the pipe essentially creates a new script with a new scope.